# Enter key don't responds when I'm trying to push var into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I'm trying to push new name in to my array, enter key don't respond and there for I can't add another names.

Part of the JS:

```
$("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event){
 if(event.which === 13){
  var newName = $(this).val();
   $("#" + "newName").append("#" + names);
   names.push(this.value);
   }
});
```

My [Codepen](https://codepen.io/nadav-himmelfarb/pen/RJaPPJ?editors=0101)

Comment: Have you looked into array.push() ?

Comment: Are you attempting to add the string value in `newName` to the array? It looks like you're instead trying to target the element with that id and append the array to it as text...?

Comment: `if (event.which === 13) names.push(this.value);`  and done

Comment: (I rewrite my question) I've tried it and it and now the enter key not respond.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that:

```
var names = [
    "Nadav",
    "Yaniv",
    "Golan",
    "Asaf",
    "Boaz",
    "Moshe"
];

$("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which === 13) {
        names.push(this.value);
    }
});
```

If you type "something" in your `input` field, then press **Return** key, you `names` array have now a new item:

```
var names = [
    "Nadav",
    "Yaniv",
    "Golan",
    "Asaf",
    "Boaz",
    "Moshe",
    "something"
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easiest way to add it to the array, based on your code:

```
var names = [


 "Nadav",
  "Yaniv",
  "Golan",
  "Asaf",
  "Boaz",
  "Moshe"
]

$("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which === 13){
        var newName = $(this).val();
        $("#" + "newName").append("#" + names); //WHAT ARE YOU DOING HERE EXACTLY?
        names.push(newName); //THIS IS THE DIFFERENT LINE 
    }
});
```

That will add the name to the names array.  However, what exactly are you doing with that line that I've commented on?